# Turning a 1x1 data frame into value

Tags: r, dplyr

I'm using `dplyr` to transform a large data frame, and I want to store the DF's most recent date + 1 as a value. I know there's easier ways to do this by breaking up the statements, but I'm trying to do it all with one pipe statement. I ran into something and I'm not sure why R defaults that way. Example:

```
Day <- seq.Date(as.Date('2017-12-01'), as.Date('2018-02-03'), 'day')
Day <- sample(Day, length(Day))
ID <- sample(c(1:5), length(Day), replace = T)

df <- data.frame(ID, Day)

foo <- df %>% 
  arrange(desc(Day)) %>% 
  mutate(DayPlus = as.Date(Day) + 1) %>% 
  select(DayPlus) #%>% 
  #slice(1)

foo <- foo[1,1]
```

When I run this code, `foo` becomes a value equal to `2018-02-04` as desired. However, when I run the code with `slice` uncommented:

```
foo <- df %>% 
  arrange(desc(Day)) %>% 
  mutate(DayPlus = as.Date(Day) + 1) %>% 
  select(DayPlus) %>% 
  slice(1)

foo <- foo[1,1]
```

`foo` stays as a dataframe. My main question is why `foo` doesn't become a value in the second example, and my second question is if there's an easy way get the "2018-02-04" as a value stored as `foo` all from one `dplyr` pipe.

Thanks

Comment: Perhaps you are looking for `pull`. Or just do `max(df$Day) + 1`

Comment: I'll check out `pull` thanks. And yeah that would definitely work in this instance, but I have to do a lot of df manipulation before I get to the current `Day`/`ID` table in my actual code and I'd rather have it all in one statement.

Comment: `<the-long-pipe> %>% summarise(max(Day) + 1) %>% pull()`

Comment: Does anyone know why this was marked as a duplicate?  Neither of the referenced questions address extracting a scalar from a 1x1 dataframe/tibble; they're both about extracting a column as a vector.  Maybe a better understanding of R's strange typing system would make it more obvious, but for an R novice like myself, there isn't an apparent connection.

Answer (score 2):

That's because your first snippet returns a `data.frame`, the second one returns a `tibble`. `tibble`s are similar to `data.frame`s, but one major difference is subsetting. If you have a `data.frame`, `foo[1, 1]` returns the first row of the first column as a vector, whereas if you have a `tibble` it returns the first row of the first column as a `tibble`.

```
df %>% 
  arrange(desc(Day)) %>% 
  mutate(DayPlus = as.Date(Day) + 1) %>% 
  select(DayPlus) %>%
  class()
```

returns

```
[1] "data.frame"
```

whereas the second one

```
df %>% 
  arrange(desc(Day)) %>% 
  mutate(DayPlus = as.Date(Day) + 1) %>% 
  select(DayPlus) %>% 
  slice(1) %>%
  class()
```

returns

```
[1] "tbl_df"     "tbl"        "data.frame"
```